# Flask-Admin: Why QuerySelectField does not work in custom edit view?

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-admin

I have the following problem:
on stack Flask, Sqlalchemy, Flask-Admin created the following models:

```
class Store(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    address = db.Column(db.String(200))

    users = db.relationship('User', backref='store', lazy='dynamic')

class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    store_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('store.id'))
    name = db.Column(db.String(128))
    login = db.Column(db.String(20))
    password = db.Column(db.String(20))
```

I use the following forms and views:

```
class UserForm(FlaskForm):
    store_id = QuerySelectField('Склад', query_factory=lambda: Store.query)
    name = StringField('Name')
    login = StringField('Login')
    password = StringField('Password')

class AdminSet(AdminModelView):
    def edit_form(self, obj=None):
        form = UserForm(obj=obj)
        return form
```

The view works without problems, but when I try to save the changes, the following error appears:

```
Failed to update record. (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) can't adapt type 'Store' [SQL: UPDATE "user" SET    store_id=%(store_id)s WHERE "user".id = %(user_id)s] [parameters: {'store_id': <Store 2>, 'user_id': 2}] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)
```

Why is this happening and what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

From the [WTForms documentation](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/0.6.1/ext.html#wtforms.ext.sqlalchemy.fields.QuerySelectField):

"The data property actually will store/keep an ORM model instance, not the ID."

Change your form definition to the following:

```
class UserForm(FlaskForm):
    store = QuerySelectField('Склад', query_factory=lambda: Store.query)
    name = StringField('Name')
    login = StringField('Login')
    password = StringField('Password')
```